# Looking for "Data gathering is hard and expensive"

Tags: references, dataset, survey

I've finished some data mining and machine learning courses and in most of them at the very beginning has been said: "Collecting and pre-processing data is the most expensive and hardest part of the Data-Mining (DM) or Machine-Learning(ML)." I remember something about at least 70 percent of costs for data collecting and cleaning.
I am finishing my thesis and one part is presenting DM results. However, I was not able to collect as much data I wanted (for objective reasons, that's not the problem).

I am looking for some trusted authority (book, paper) to state (cite) "data gathering is hard". I have several books on DM or ML, but all of them start with data pre-processing and this is the phase when you have all data you need.

Comment: Please explain what the acronyms DM, ML and DMA are.

Comment: Anyone who has professional experience in data knows that collection and cleaning are the two most expensive tasks. The types of places that you'll find these claims in articles are in that annoying marketing-type literature that circulates on LinkedIn, to explain in glossy form to executives and program managers just what "those nerds in analytics" have been grumbling about all these years. Tech and consulting firms selling stuff in this arena will quote figures of how much that costs, acquired by some kind of BCG/CEB/Delloitte/McKinsey-type research.